# What is the best way to check if a record exists in a SQL Server table using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best way?  To get a 1 or 0 back?  Or check if rows are available from a query?  I'm arguing for ExecuteScalar but interested in other answers why or why not.

```
//using DataReader.HasRows?
bool result = false;

var cmd = new SqlCommand("select foo, bar from baz where id = 123", _sqlConnection, _sqlTransaction);

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (r != null && r.HasRows)
    {
        result = true;
    }
}

return result;

//or using Scalar?
bool result = false;

var cmd = new SqlCommand("if exists(select foo, bar from baz where id = 123) select 1 else select 0", _sqlConnection, _sqlTransaction);

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

int i = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
result = i == 1;
return result;
```

Comment: Do you want the results of the query as well or just an indicator if there _would_ be any results?

Comment: Third option would be to use `select top 1 1 from...` which at least sounds the simplest. You should anyhow look into execution plan & statistics io output if you're interested what happens in the database side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exists is more efficient than Count, because count needs to scan all rows to match the criteria and include in the count, exist dont.

So exists with ExecuteScalar is better.

As more info backing this:

According to http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx

> Both queries scanned the table but the EXISTS was able to at least do
>   a partial scan do to the fact it can stop after it finds the very
>   first matching row. Where as the COUNT(*) must read each and every row
>   in the entire table to determine if they match the criteria and how
>   many there are. That is the key folks. The ability to stop working
>   after the first row that meets the criteria of the WHERE clause is
>   what makes EXISTS so efficient.  The optimizer knows of this behavior
>   and can factor that in as well. Now keep in mind that these tables are
>   relatively small compared to most databases in the real world. So the
>   figures of the COUNT(*) queries would be multiplied many times on
>   larger tables. You could easily get hundred's of thousands of reads or
>   more on tables with millions of rows but the EXISTS will still only
>   have just a few reads on any queries that can use an index to satisfy
>   the WHERE clause.

As a simple experiment using AdventureWorks with MSSQL 2012

```
set showplan_all on

-- TotalSubtreeCost: 0.06216168
select count(*) from sales.Customer

-- TotalSubtreeCost: 0.003288537
select 1 where exists (select * from sales.Customer)
```

See also

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/exists-vs-count

UPDATE: On ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteReader.
Having a look with a disassembler (like Reflector) on the Implementation of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand methods, shows something surprising, they are kind of equivalent: both end up calling the internal helper 
**internal SqlDataReader RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, bool returnStream, string method, TaskCompletionSource completion, int timeout, out Task task, bool asyncWrite = false)**

which returns a SqlDataReader, the ExecuteReader returns it as is.
While ExecuteScalar consumes it with another helper:

```
private object CompleteExecuteScalar(SqlDataReader ds, bool returnSqlValue)
{
    object obj2 = null;
    try
    {
        if (!ds.Read() || (ds.FieldCount <= 0))
        {
            return obj2;
        }
        if (returnSqlValue)
        {
            return ds.GetSqlValue(0);
        }
        obj2 = ds.GetValue(0);
    }
    finally
    {
        ds.Close();
    }
    return obj2;
}
```

As a side note, same goes with MySQL Connector/NET (The official ADO.NET open source driver for MySQL), the method ExecuteScalar internally creates an DataReader (MySqlDataReader to be more precise) and consumes it. See on source file /Src/Command.cs (from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ or https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net).

Summary: Regarding the ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteReader both incurr in the overhead of creating a SqlDataReader, I would say the difference is mostly idiomatic.

Comment: Count is obviously least effective. What can you say about ExecuteScalar vs ExecuteReader ?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I updated the answer to add some details on the matter.

Comment: I suspected that DataReader takes part in every select operations. In this case .ExecuteReader() is more effective. The Less The Better.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with `ExecuteScalar` with a query like your `if exists`. It should be as fast as possible on the server and with minimal network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about existence, I would use the scalar approach but also update the TSQL to be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ExecuteScalar` with a slightly different query:

```
string sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN exists(select  NULL from baz where id = 123) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _sqlConnection, _sqlTransaction);
```